# What changes occur in Account Teams

Tags: account-teams

I am quite new to Teams concept of sharing in SF and still learning. What will happen if one of the Account's members access is changed after it is added to the default Account Team?

Does it change all its related object teams and if so, what will be the changes?

Comment: can you provide some example of your question